# Joomla 3.3.6 show article not on frontpage because I got hidden content on frontpage

Tags: joomla, hide, show, article, frontpage

I got a problem with my joomla 3.3.6 website

To make a nice custom homepage i hide all the content of the frontpage with this code:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu(); ?>

<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) : ?>
<?php echo ''; ?>
<?php else : ?>
...........
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I got a page with all kind of news articles, but when I press one article it goes to my frontpage, When I delete the code above it shows the content of the article of the bottom of my homepage, but I don't want that.

Comment: So are you trying to hide the view/article on the homepage only?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question,   But i got a module showing 5 articles of a category, when i press a article, it shows the full article on the homepage with all my homepage modules.

I want it to show up on a other page where i can assign other modules to that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,

just made a new category and moves all categorys of the news inside that category and for that one i made a hidden menu item